# Re-uploading an existing file to Box through the API returning a 500 error

Tags: box-api

I'm building tests around an api wrapper in PHP, and I'm not getting the expected response when I try to re-upload an existing file based on the API documentation.

According to the docs:

> If the name of the file being uploaded already exists in the folder, an error is returned.

While technically speaking returning a 500 response code is an error, I assume that the intended behaviour would be an error returned in the errors format outlined in the API docs.

The response includes the following content in it's body, making me even more convinced this is not the intended behaviour:

> #### Your Box account is temporarily down — but you shouldn't be — because we'll be up and running soon.
>
> Thanks for your patience ... and for being the most important part of Box.
>
> During the pause, you can:
>
> Refresh your browser
>                   Check our [blog for any news](http://blog.box.net)
>                   Submit a [support ticket](http://support.box.com/tickets/new)

Comment: There might be something wrong with your request. When I try to upload a file of the same name to a folder I get a 409 conflict error

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that a normal file-upload via the API is working?  500 error codes from Box typically mean you should just turn around and re-try your upload because something is very temporarily wrong.   In some cases it may mean that you are hitting a URL that isn't valid for doing uploads, or the server doesn't have enough info to try to figure out what your HTTP POST is trying to do.

If you include your specific POST, and the JSON or XML response you're getting back, we can help debug what might be going wrong.  Please don't include your actual API-key and Auth_token as this is a public forum...